# Solving for x: $13^{2x+1} - 13^x -12=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$13^{2x+1} - 13^x -12=0$$

This is equality that i didn't understand because there is $+1$ on power. If there wasn't +1 on power it would be same as quadratic equality

Comment: Hint: $13^{2x+1} - 13^x -12=13y^2 - y -12=0$

Comment: $t=13^x$ gives $13t^2-t-12=0$ . Only the positive solution $t=1$ gives a solution, namely $x=0$.

Comment: $13^{2x + 1} = 13^{2x} \times 13$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'a basic index law: $a^{m+n}= a^m\cdot a^n$

Now, your equations simplifies to:

$13^{2x}\cdot13- 13^x-12=0$

Let $13^x= k$.

Thus, 
$13k^2-k-12=0   \implies k=-\dfrac{12}{13}\quad \mathrm{or} \quad k=  1$
$\implies13^x=-\frac{12}{13} $ or $13^x=1$

Hence, the only real solution is $x=0$

Comment: Hm I still don't get it "Thus $13k^2-k-12=0$ which yields $13^x=-\frac{12}{13} $ or $13^x=1$" - how did you get rid of the $13k^2$? And why $13^x=1$?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $t=13^x$ and solve $13t^2-t-12=0$.

Comment: where is +1 $13^{2x+1}$

Comment: As I told you $13^{2x + 1} = 13^{2x} \times 13$

Comment: $13t^2=13\times 13^{2x}=13^{2x+1}$.

Comment: Understood @C.F.G

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the $+1$ by using the fact that $a^{b+c}=a^b\cdot a^c$ and writing $$13^{2x+1} = 13^{2x}\cdot 13^1$$